# how to show mutiple image in grid like facebook and linked in

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, customization

[image: Example Image]

I need to show multiple image in grid like example given here.

and also need plus icon while images is more than some certain counts

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement it

- Two horizontal/vertical [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout)
- [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout) with two rows
- [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout?hl=en) which its children are chained together
- [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/GridView?hl=en)
- [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview?hl=en) with GridLayoutManager
- and more ... :D

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want to fetch the images dynamically, and there are several collection views: [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView/), [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView/) etc. RecyclerView is common since you can modify the layout(for your case, columns) with various [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager)s. Since you haven't provide any code, I cannot help you with that, but [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview/) is a guide that might be helpful.

For the plus icon mechanism, you can modify your RecyclerViewAdapter code, limiting the count(in `getItemCount()`) to a certain number and visible a transculent foreground with '+number' in the ViewHolder code for the last item.